# Setting up the network for Kubernetes

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, subnet

I'm reading the [Kubernetes "*Getting Started from Scratch*" Guide](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch.html) and have arrived at the dreaded [**Network Section**](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/networking.html#kubernetes-model), where they state:

```
Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any networking implementation
(barring any intentional network segmentation policies):
* all containers can communicate with all other containers without NAT
* all nodes can communicate with all containers (and vice-versa) without NAT
* the IP that a container sees itself as is the same IP that others see it as
```

My first source of confusion is: **How is this *different* than the "standard" Docker model?** How is Docker different w.r.t. those 3 Kubernetes requirements?

The article then goes on to summarize how GCE achieves these requirements:

> For the Google Compute Engine cluster configuration scripts, we use advanced routing to assign each VM a subnet (default is /24 - 254 IPs). Any traffic bound for that subnet will be routed directly to the VM by the GCE network fabric. This is in addition to the "main" IP address assigned to the VM, which is NAT'ed for outbound internet access. A linux bridge (called cbr0) is configured to exist on that subnet, and is passed to docker's --bridge flag.

My question here is: **Which requirement(s) from the 3 above does this paragraph address? More importantly, *how* does it achieve the requirement(s)?** I guess I just don't understand how 1-subnet-per-VM accomplishes: container-container communication, node-container communication, and static IP.

---

And, as a bonus/stretch concern: Why doesn't Marathon suffer from the same networking concerns as what Kubernetes is addressing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Docker's standard [networking configuration](https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/) picks a container subnet for you out of its [chosen defaults](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/vendor/src/github.com/docker/libnetwork/drivers/bridge/setup_ipv4.go#L25). As long as it doesn't conflict with any interfaces on your host, Docker is okay with it.

Then, Docker inserts an iptables MASQUERADE rule that allows containers to talk to the external world using the host's default interface.

Kubernetes' 3 requirements are violated by the fact that subnets are chosen only based on addresses in use on the host, which forces the requirement to NAT all container traffic using the MASQUERADE rule.

Consider the following 3-host Docker setup (a little contrived to highlight things):

### Host 1:

**eth0**: 10.1.2.3

**docker0**: 172.17.42.1/16

**container-A**: 172.17.42.2

### Host 2:

**eth0**: 10.1.2.4

**docker0**: 172.17.42.1/16

**container-B**: 172.17.42.2

### Host 3:

**eth0**: 172.17.42.2

**docker0**: 172.18.42.1

Let's say **container-B** wants to access an HTTP service on port 80 of **container-A**. You can get docker to expose **container-A**'s port 80 somewhere on **Host 1**. Then **container-B** might make a request to 10.1.2.3:43210. This will be received on **container-A**'s port 80, but will look like it came from some random port on 10.1.2.4 because of the NAT on the way out of **Host 2**. This violates the *all containers communicate without NAT* and the *container sees same IP as others* requirements. Try to access **container-A**'s service directly from **Host 2** and you get your *nodes can communicate with containers without NAT* violation.

Now if either of those containers want to talk to **Host 3**, they're SOL (just a general argument for being careful with the auto-assigned docker0 subnets).

Kubernetes approach on GCE/AWS/Flannel/... is to [assign](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/node/nodecontroller.go#L364) each host VM a subnet carved out of a flat private network. No subnets overlap with VM addresses or with each other. This lets containers and VMs communicate NATlessly.

Comment: Thanks for such an awesome answer @CJ Cullen (+1) - a few quick followups for you should shore this up for me, and the lightbulbs are already starting to turn on. **(1)** When you say that Docker chooses a subnet for you, you mean it chooses a subnet *mask*, right? Can you confirm that what you mean is that the subnet mask is deliberately chosen so as to *not* to conflict with an IP address in use on the host? If so, how exactly can a subnet mask conflict with a host IP? **(2)** Why does this "subnet mask" selection strategy force the router to NAT all traffic from the host?

Comment: **(3)** You say "*Then container-B might make a request to 10.1.2.3:43210. This will be received on container-A's port 80, but will look like it came from some random port on 10.1.2.4 because of the NAT on the way out of Host 2.*” Can you explain this a little more? Why would a request to port 43210 be received on port 80? How does NAT obfuscate the egress IP/port coming from Host 2?

Comment: **(4)** Why is Kubernetes so concerned about *not* using NAT?!? What’s so bad about it? And finally (I know sorry!) **(5)** When you say "*Now if either of those containers want to talk to Host 3, they're SOL*”…why?!? I'm just not seeing it. Thanks again for any and all help/clarity here!

Comment: **(1)** Docker chooses the whole subnet (e.g. 172.17.42.1/16). The subnet mask is just the "/16" part. Docker avoids conflicts w/ addresses in use on the host. For example, if the default interface (or the local nameserver) had the IP 172.17.42.2, Docker wouldn't be able to choose 172.17.42.1/16 (because it includes 172.17.42.2).

**(2)** Because Docker can only look at locally used addresses, the addresses it assigns containers might conflict with other things in your network. It can assume that your host IP is unique on the network (otherwise everything else would break).

Comment: **(3)** In order to expose the service to other machines, you'd have to bind the container port to a host port (see https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#binding-ports). Port 43210 was the host port I chose as an example.
**(4)** Kubernetes' service model depends a flat networking space, among other reasons (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/networking.md#model-and-motivation).
**(5)** Host 3 and the containers have the same IP. To communicate, they'll have to do some sort of funky NATing (i.e. how does container-B say "get these packets to Host 3"?).