# Running Kubernetes on vCenter

Tags: networking, kubernetes

So Kubernetes has a pretty novel network model, that I believe is based on what it perceives to be a shortcoming with default Docker networking. While I'm still struggling to understand: (1) what it perceives the actual shortcoming(s) to be, and (2) what Kubernetes' general solution is, I'm now reaching a point where I'd like to just implement the solution and perhaps that will clue me in a little better.

Whereas the rest of the Kubernetes documentation is very mature and well-written, the instructions for configuring the network are sparse, largely incoherent, and span many disparate articles, instead of being located in one particular place.

I'm hoping someone who has set up a Kubernetes cluster before (from scratch) can help walk me through the basic procedures. I'm not interested in running on GCE or AWS, and for now I'm not interested in using any kind of overlay network like `flannel`.

My *basic* understanding is:

1. Carve out a `/16` subnet for all your pods. This will limit you to some 65K pods, which should be sufficient for most normal applications. All IPs in this subnet must be "public" and not inside of some traditionally-private (classful) range.
2. Create a `cbr0` bridge somewhere and make sure its persistent (**but on what machine?**)
3. Remove/disable the `MASQUERADE` rule installed by Docker.
4. Some how configure `iptables` routes (again, **where?**) so that each pod spun up by Kubernetes receives one of those public IPs.
5. Some other setup is required to make use of load balanced `Services` and dynamic DNS.
6. Provision 5 VMs: 1 master, 4 minions
7. Install/configure Docker on all 5 VMs
8. Install/configure `kubectl`, `controller-manager`, `apiserver` and `etcd` to the master, and run them as services/daemons
9. Install/configure `kubelet` and `kube-proxy` on each minion and run them as services/daemons

This is the best I can collect from 2 full days of research, and they are likely wrong (or misdirected), out of order, and utterly incomplete.

I have unbridled access to create VMs in an on-premise vCenter cluster. If changes need to be made to VLAN/Switches/etc. I can get infrastructure involved.

**How many VMs should I set up for Kubernetes (for a small-to-medium sized cluster), and why? What exact corrections do I need to make to my vague instructions above, so as to get networking totally configured?**

I'm good with installing/configuring all the binaries. Just totally choking on the network side of the setup.

Answer (score 3):

For a general introduction into kubernetes networking, I found http://www.slideshare.net/enakai/architecture-overview-kubernetes-with-red-hat-enterprise-linux-71 pretty helpful.

On your items (1) and (2): IMHO they are nicely described in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/admin/networking.md#docker-model . 
From my experience: What is the Problem with the Docker NAT type of approach? Sometimes you need to configure e.g. into the software all the endpoints of all nodes (172.168.10.1:8080, 172.168.10.2:8080, etc). in kubernetes you can simply configure the IP's of the pods into each others pod, Docker complicates it using NAT indirection. 
See also [Setting up the network for Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32852216/setting-up-the-network-for-kubernetes) for a nice answer.

Comments on your other points:
1.

> All IPs in this subnet must be "public" and not inside of some traditionally-private (classful) range.

The "internal network" of kubernetes normally uses private IP's, see also slides above, which uses 10.x.x.x as example. I guess confusion comes from some kubernetes texts that refer to "public" as "visible outside of the node", but they do not mean "Internet Public IP Address Range".

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Vailant (+1), I appreciate the links and explanations. However, I think you missed the main focus of my question, which is the **bolded** sentence above starting "*How many VMs should I set up for Kubernetes...*". The main focus of the question (and bounty!) is to put together a set of concrete steps for setting up Kubernetes on vCenter. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi smeeb, I agree to your comment. Sorry, no thoughts from my side, I mainly wanted to get the discussion started, as your question was unanswered for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested in doing the same, here is my current plan.

I found the [`kube-up.sh`](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.html) script which installs a production-ish quality Kubernetes cluster on your AWS account. Essentially it creates 1 Kubernetes master EC2 instance and 4 minion instances.

On the master it installs etcd, apiserver, controller manager, and the scheduler. On the minions it installs kubelet and kube-proxy. It also creates an auto-scaling group for the minions (nice), and creates a whole slew of security- and networking-centric things on AWS for you. **If you run the script and it fails creating the AWS S3 bucket, create a bucket of the same exact name manually and then re-run the script.**

When the script is finished you will have Kubernetes up and running and ready for near-production usage (I keep saying "near" and "production-ish" because I'm too new to Kubernetes to know what actually constitutes a real deal productionalized cluster). You will need the AWS CLI installed and configured with a user that has full admin access to your AWS account (it goes ahead and creates IAM roles, etc.).

My game plan will be to:

1. Get comfortable working with Kubernetes on AWS
2. Keep hounding the Kubernetes team on [Slack](https://kubernetes.slack.com/messages) to help me understand how Kubernetes works under the hood
3. Reverse engineer the `kube-up.sh` script so that I can get Kubernetes running on premise (vCenter)
4. Blog about this process
5. Update this answer with a link to said blog.

Give me some time and I'll follow through.